# Can't stop service

Tags: android, service, android-service

I'm develop application that start service for getting info from server via POST-request.
In my case, user can cancelled load data (when he choose item in `ListView` started new Activity where I start service in Thread).

Now if user press Back for return to previos activity I called `stopService(intent)`. Method `onDestroy()` is called, but loading data from Internet don't stop

My start point for service:

```
private void makeNewSync() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewsLoaderService.class);
                intent.putExtra("NEW_GLOBAL_ID", newGlobalId);
                startService(intent);
            }
        });
        thread.setPriority(10);
        thread.start();
    }
```

My back button listener:

```
     @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                if (isFullScreen) {
                    changeFullScreenMode(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewsLoaderService.class));
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
```

onDestroy() method of my service:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("MyLOg", "loader service is: " + isRunning + " stopped.");
        if (isRunning) {
            isRunning = false;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: unbind your service first ..

Answer (score 0):

when you use stopService method to stop service this will call onDestroy method of your Service if your service is currently running.and inside the onDestory method you write the code to stop your task.

Comment: Which code can kill my service (task with service)?

Comment: for example if service method onStartCommand starts Thread then  you can call Thread.stop() method .

Comment: It just an example how to stop background tasks of the service.you can  use flag variable and make it false inside of onDestory method of the service.

Answer (score 0):

don't start service in seperate thread or use IntentService in your case or start service by handler since service runs in ui thread

Comment: Start service in UI thread if he work with INTERNET? System called android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.
You question is not good idea